# tidyverse and jsonlite - convert a nested JSON ticker feed into a one row dataframe

Tags: r

Want to constrain solution to tidyverse packages.  Struggling with converting a nested JSON into a one row dataframe.  It's a feed from kafka that i need to process for an intra day trading scenario.

The objective is one row:  EventTime in col1, rest of the columns are the TICKER names with price.  Time, AAPL, DBC, JPM... are the column labels and then price as the row.  I get close but..

I get stuck trying to access the nested list.

raw data:

```
from_kafka = '{"eventTime":1547831236883,"ticker":{"AAPL":{"lastTrade":146.92,"totalVolume":309985.0},"DBC":{"lastTrade":14.82,"totalVolume":7366.0},"JPM":{"lastTrade":99.56,"totalVolume":63695.0},"JNJ":{"lastTrade":127.21,"totalVolume":24515.0},"MRK":{"lastTrade":75.52,"totalVolume":41928.0},"PFE":{"lastTrade":42.57,"totalVolume":87949.0}}}'
```

Comes in fine using the jsonlite package

```
row_raw <- fromJSON(from_kafka)

str(row_raw)

List of 2
$ eventTime: num 1547831236883
$ ticker   :List of 6
..$ AAPL:List of 2
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 147
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 309985
..$ DBC :List of 2
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 14.8
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 7366
..$ JPM :List of 2
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 99.6
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 63695
..$ JNJ :List of 2
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 127
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 24515
..$ MRK :List of 2
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 75.5
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 41928
..$ PFE :List of 2
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 42.6
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 87949
```

okay now i am stuck..

```
row_incoming_convert <-row_raw %>% purrr::flatten() %>% 
map_if(is_list,as_tibble) %>% map_if(is_tibble,list) %>% bind_cols()
```

I get one row, but each row is the darn list.  I can't figure out how to access this list, remove `totalVolume` variable and just show `lastTrade` price only.  Purrr seems to be made for this.

```
> row_incoming_convert

> str(row_incoming_convert)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:
$ eventTime: num 1547831236883
$ AAPL     :List of 1
..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 
variables:
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 147
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 309985
$ DBC      :List of 1
..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 
variables:
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 14.8
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 7366
$ JPM      :List of 1
..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 
variables:
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 99.6
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 63695
$ JNJ      :List of 1
..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 
variables:
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 127
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 24515
$ MRK      :List of 1
..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 
variables:
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 75.5
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 41928
$ PFE      :List of 1
..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 
variables:
.. ..$ lastTrade  : num 42.6
.. ..$ totalVolume: num 87949


> row_incoming_convert
# A tibble: 1 x 7
eventTime AAPL             DBC              JPM              JNJ              
MRK              PFE             
<dbl> <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>           
<list>           <list>          
1   1.55e12 <tibble [1 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 2]> 
<tibble [1 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 2]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you really want for your final output. It'd be nice if you post the desired result (even a reduced one). In any case:

```
library(magrittr)

from_kafka = '{"eventTime":1547831236883,"ticker":{"AAPL":{"lastTrade":146.92,"totalVolume":309985.0},"DBC":{"lastTrade":14.82,"totalVolume":7366.0},"JPM":{"lastTrade":99.56,"totalVolume":63695.0},"JNJ":{"lastTrade":127.21,"totalVolume":24515.0},"MRK":{"lastTrade":75.52,"totalVolume":41928.0},"PFE":{"lastTrade":42.57,"totalVolume":87949.0}}}'

row_raw <- jsonlite::fromJSON(from_kafka, flatten = T)

res <- row_raw %>%
  unlist %>% 
  t %>% 
  as.data.frame(., stringsAsFalse = T)

# if you wish to remove "ticker" from the df col names...
names(res) <- gsub(x = names(res), pattern = "^ticker\\.", "")
```

Result:

```
> res
     eventTime AAPL.lastTrade AAPL.totalVolume DBC.lastTrade
1 1.547831e+12         146.92           309985         14.82
  DBC.totalVolume JPM.lastTrade JPM.totalVolume JNJ.lastTrade
1            7366         99.56           63695        127.21
  JNJ.totalVolume MRK.lastTrade MRK.totalVolume PFE.lastTrade
1           24515         75.52           41928         42.57
  PFE.totalVolume
1           87949
```

Comment: sweet - this looks great thx.  To answer your query: eventTime, AAPl, DBC, etc.. as row headers.  Then 1 row, event time value, lastTrade price for each ticker. Volume deleted.

Comment: So you don't want `*.totalVolume` columns?

Comment: Nope, no volume - thats what i struggled with, how to remove that from the nested list

Comment: You don't need to delete from the nested list, you can add to the `res <- ...` piping at the end: `res <- ... %>% dplyr::select_if(., .predicate = !stringr::str_detect(string = names(.), pattern = "(?i)totalvolume"))` and that would take care of the `totalVolume` columns...

Comment: perfect - really appreciate the help

Comment: The new version of dplyr 0.8.0.1 is causing an exception now.  Worked fine with previous verisons.  Error: Can't create call to non-callable object.  row_clean <- row_raw %>%
  unlist %>% 
  t %>% 
  as.data.frame(., stringsAsFalse = T) %>%  dplyr::select_if(., .predicate = !stringr::str_detect(string = names(.), pattern = "(?i)totalvolume"))